# How to create "New Gradle Project" in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gradle

1. Installed Gradle plugin.
2. Create New Gradle Project in eclipse
3. On click of Finish, getting following error :

No trusted certificate found
Could not install Gradle distribution from 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.0-bin.zip'.

Please guide me how to make new Gradle Java based project in eclipse. Should I need any pre configuration to use Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

In my case..

Window -> Preferences -> Gradle -> Gradle Distribution

Change selection 'Use Gradle wrapper's default' to Folder and set the gradle installed path

Comment: Did you get a similar error msg before using `your` configuration ?

Comment: @chouaib yes exactly same massage

Answer (score 0):

We need to make new entries in Window -> Preferences -> Gradle

Under Gradle Distribution, select the folder option and provide the path of installed Gradle Directory

And also Under Gradle User Home, select the directory option and provide the path of .gradle [This path would be most probably found at C:/Users/XYZ/.gradle]

[image]